# Android: wake lock: is lock released on application paused?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I have to use the wakelock (yes I shouldn't for the obvious reasons but I'm being paid to do it so I don't have a choice lol)

my question is very simple: when I leave the app onPause or onStop, is the wake lock of the app automatically released ?

I want to avoid the user closing his app and the wake lock is still on for some weird reason.

I'm having an issue with my current system where the app is calling up the release wake lock through a message handler (because its coming from another thread) and this happens "too late" and the app crashes because it does no longer have the reference to the wake lock.

I might not be very clear but the main question here is :

do I have to worry about the wake lock of my app affecting the phone outside the life cycle of the app.

cheers

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my question is very simple: when I leave the app onPause or onStop, is the wake lock of the app automatically released ?

Nope. Which is why you should use `android:keepScreenOn` in an activity rather than a `WakeLock`.

> do I have to worry about the wake lock of my app affecting the phone outside the life cycle of the app.

Absolutely. Until you release that `WakeLock`, the phone will not fall asleep.

Comment: what I really need to do is release the wake lock in the onPause method every time?

Comment: @Jason Rogers: Again, it would be better to use `android:keepScreenOn`.

Answer (score 0):

Wake lock DEFINITELY affects your device even if you application is NOT in foreground !

That's actually the whole point of acquiring wake locks

So, make sure you ONLY use wake locks when you have no other option, and if you don't need wake lock when your app is in background, make sure to release wake lock in onPause() method !

This will drastically affect your device 's performance and BATTERY !

Answer (score -3):

When your application is no longer the focus the wake lock is cancelled, only when your application is the focus is the wake lock in affect.

Comment: This is incorrect AFAIK. If you have a sample application that demonstrates this, please post a link!